# Can't start junit test when application class is customized

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-testing, android-application-class

When I try to start one of my `junit` tests, all of them fail due to multiple errors. This is due to the fact, that my `Application class` has some variables in it, which are initialized in the "normal" app start, but not when I start a test. Commenting the variables out might help, but that is an ugly solution, to always comment stuff out, when starting a test.

### Application Class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
@InternalCoroutinesApi
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory
    @Inject lateinit var workerList: WorkerList
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        plantTimberTree()
        enableOfflinePersistence()
        workerList.startDownloadDocumentWork()
    }

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration =
        Configuration.Builder().setWorkerFactory(workerFactory).build()
}

private fun plantTimberTree() = Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())

private fun enableOfflinePersistence() {
    val settings = firestoreSettings { isPersistenceEnabled = true }
    Firebase.firestore.firestoreSettings = settings
}
```

### TestCase

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(maxSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P, minSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
class EmailViewModelTest {


}
```

### Error Stacktrace (without any comment)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process null. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:184)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(FirebaseFirestore.java:91)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.FirestoreKt.getFirestore(Firestore.kt:32)
    at com.example.app.AppKt.enableOfflinePersistence(App.kt:44)
    at com.example.app.AppKt.access$enableOfflinePersistence(App.kt:1)
    at com.example.app.App.onCreate(App.kt:24)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.lambda$installAndCreateApplication$0(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:288)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:75)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.installAndCreateApplication(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:288)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.setUpApplicationState(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:171)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:319)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:254)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

### Error Stacktrace (when commenting "enableOfflicePersistence" out)

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property workerList has not been initialized

    at com.example.app.App.onCreate(App.kt:25)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.lambda$installAndCreateApplication$0(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:288)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:75)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.installAndCreateApplication(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:288)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.setUpApplicationState(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:171)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:319)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:254)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there a way to determine, whether a test has been started or not? How should I change my Application class in order to get my tests running again?

I appreciate every help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using RobolectricTestRunner.

There's a couple different ways to solve the problem of FirebaseApp getting into weird states during a Robolectric test vs how it would behave if your Application class had been initialized normally.

(1) You can use Robolectric to specify a special test Application context to use that does whatever you want with Firebase.

(2) You can use Roboelectric to create a shadow class for FirebaseApp that behaves in whatever way you desire. (Here's one [example](https://gist.github.com/Turnsole/506feebcb282a4c9c11d1f90591d84af) in which I have the shadow class catch that exception you referenced and initialize Firebase.)

The advantage of writing a shadow class for FirebaseApp is that it can be configured to intervene for any way your code may access FirebaseApp, and a [robolectric.properties file](http://robolectric.org/configuring/#robolectricproperties-file) can configure your whole test package.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by implementing Roboelectric library as it provides the android environment to run your tests.

Check the below link to get detailed description how to use it. I found it very useful.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-basics/#0

Comment: I think, I am already using the roboeletrictestrunner, am I? I've edited my question

Comment: try @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) instead. Also add some tests(even blank ones will be ok) as the blank test class can also throw errors as much as I know.

Comment: Unfortunately, no difference.

Comment: do you have blank test class?

Comment: No, there are test cases in my test class. Over 60

Comment: FirebaseApp.initializeApp() add this in @Before of your test class.

Comment: No difference, but when I comment "enableOfflincePersistence" out, the next error comes.. "lateinit property wokerList has not been initialized". I don't think that I have to change something in my test at all. It has something to do with the Application class

Comment: @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule() try adding this in test. I hope this should run bro.